# How can I initialize a list of sublists of sublists from a one dimensional list or array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a function which creates a list of lists of lists:

```py
def initialize_master_list(n, h, o):
    master_list = []
    master_list.append([[0 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(h)])
    master_list.append([[0 for i in range(h+1)] for j in range(o)])
    return master_list
```

This creates a list of `2` lists, where the first is a list of `h` lists of length `n+1` and the second is a list of `o` lists of length `h+1`. This function initializes each of the deepest list's elements as `0`. Here I've printed what the list looks like:

```py
N, H, O = 4, 3, 2
ML = initialize_master_list(N, H, O)
print(ML)
```

`[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]`

Instead of `0`, I want to initialize these values as coming from a one-dimensional list or array of values. This 1D list is of length `(h * n+1) + (o * h+1)`. For the current example, the length is `(3 * 5) + (2 * 4) = 15 + 8 = 23`.

For example:

```py
GRAB = [round(random.uniform(1, 9),1) for _ in range((H*(N+1))+(O*(H+1)))]
print(GRAB)
```

`[7.4, 5.7, 5.3, 7.1, 2.7, 4.3, 4.1, 7.0, 1.4, 1.4, 2.2, 3.2, 1.6, 8.4, 5.7, 2.0, 4.5, 7.8, 4.1, 5.1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]`

How can I initialize `ML` using these values, in order, instead?

My expected output might be:

```py
ML = initialize_master_list(N, H, O, GRAB)
print(ML)
```

`[[[7.4, 5.7, 5.3, 7.1, 2.7], [4.3, 4.1, 7.0, 1.4, 1.4], [2.2, 3.2, 1.6, 8.4, 5.7]], [[2.0, 4.5, 7.8, 4.1], [5.1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]]]`

How can I initialize this list structure based on `N, H, O`? Those values I chose arbitrarily, they could be anything, but I can assume `GRAB` will be the exact number of numbers I want to initialize the list from.

My best idea was to make a generator and yield the values (instead of `0 for i in range...` in `initialize_master_list`, it would be `next(generator) for i in range...` but this is ugly. I'm hoping for an easier way that isn't bodging it together like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an iterator using [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch each value in order:

```
def initialize_master_list(n, h, o, g):
    it = iter(g)
    master_list = [[[next(it) for i in range(n + 1)] for j in range(h)],
                   [[next(it) for i in range(h + 1)] for j in range(o)]]
    return master_list


N, H, O = 4, 3, 2
GRAB = [7.4, 5.7, 5.3, 7.1, 2.7, 4.3, 4.1, 7.0, 1.4, 1.4, 2.2,
        3.2, 1.6, 8.4, 5.7, 2.0, 4.5, 7.8, 4.1, 5.1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]

result = initialize_master_list(N, H, O, GRAB)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[7.4, 5.7, 5.3, 7.1, 2.7], [4.3, 4.1, 7.0, 1.4, 1.4], [2.2, 3.2, 1.6, 8.4, 5.7]], [[2.0, 4.5, 7.8, 4.1], [5.1, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]]]
```

Comment: That was my initial idea (you answered this just as I edited it in, haha), I have little experience with generators or iterators, but this is a good way to solve my problem.

Comment: I answered using a generator, but think for this specific problem that `iter` is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generator seeded by the list of values and use that to populate your lists of lists:

```py
def initialize_master_list(n, h, o, l):
    master_list = []
    seeds = val_generator(l)
    master_list.append([[next(seeds) for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(h)])
    master_list.append([[next(seeds) for i in range(h+1)] for j in range(o)])
    return master_list

def val_generator(l):
    for val in l:
        yield val
```

This approach could be desirable if you want any custom logic as part of your generator.